# Sharepoint 2010 Modifying list items with Windows Store app

Tags: c#, windows-8, sharepoint-2010, windows-store-apps

I'm struggeling for weeks with this topic so im asking here:

I writing a Windows Store App for Windows Surface. This app should read the entries of a Microsoft ShrePoint 2010 list, modify them or add new values to empty fields and than upload the modified list to SharePoint. Reading the values is no problem, it works fine. The problem is the upload of the list entrys.

I found many ways to do that, but none of them worked with a Store App.

Does anyone know a way which works with C#, Sharepoint 2010 and Store App ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this example should work for creating a list item in SharePoint 2010 if you modify the links to use the 2010 REST API structure.  I do not have a 2010 environment to run a test against but this is the only way I've found to do Store Apps that work with SharePoint.

This will create an item:

```
string url = "https://YourSite.com/Subsite/";
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = true });
client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(url);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-RequestDigest", digest);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-HTTP-Method", "POST");
HttpContent content = new StringContent("{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.ReportListItem' }, 'Title': 'NewTitle', 'PhotosId': { 'results': [2] }, 'Details': 'Another successful day!' }");
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
content.Headers.ContentType.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("odata", "verbose"));
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Report')/items", content);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
}
else
{
}
```

If you replace _api/web/lists/GetByTitle('ListName')/items with _vti_bin/ListData.svc/ListName I think this example should still work.  Other tweaks will likely be needed too.  If it does I have examples of every common activity using only store libraries here:

https://arcandotnet.wordpress.com/2015/04/01/sharepoint-2013-rest-services-using-c-and-the-httpclient-for-windows-store-apps/

Comment: I've tried it but I stil have some questions.  
1. In the 5th line. The word digest hast to be in " ", right?

Comment: (sorry for double post)
2. It says 400 Bad Request. I think it's because I didn't put the right parameters into the "StringContent" Section. Do you know what I have to write there ? For example: I want only to change the value of "Nachname". How does this work ? And do you now what excactly I have to use for "type" ?

Comment: The digest is a digest string you retrieve from SharePoint via a rest call.  I have an example of how to do this in 2013 on the link above and explain how it works.  The type will be SP.Data.LISTNAMEListItem  its a weird format but it works.  To update a column, if its test just refer to 'Title' : 'NewTitle' where Title would be the column name and NewTitle is the value,   The more complex structure of 'PhotosId' is for setting a multivalue lookup column.